# Blender for Architecture

Tags: modeling

I would like to know which are the benefits of using this program in relation with the architecture. I would like to know if it is a tool from the architects to know something about lights or something like that.

I'm Adrián from Spain, and I'm discovering Blender now because I'm doing a kind of tesis about this program.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello. At Blender Stack Exchange BSE we discuss specific problems about the use of Blender.  Your question does not fit that model.  This occurs once a day or so.  You may search another site Blender Artists, where they have discussion closer to your question.  So you can change your question or it will probably be closed.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! The software is capable of running a physically based simulation of a of a scene lighting with the rendering engines (e.g. Cycles). Said that, I think you should try to be more precise about the kind of information you would like to get, because at the moment your question seems a little too broad.

Comment: You shouldn't miss http://www.thearchitectureacademy.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender is used currently for Architecture in different aspects, either to create 3D assets or to visualize and combine CG generated imagery with actual photographs.

Even though the main goals and design of the software are not scientific or technical applications, the program can generate accurate models and is suited for different styles of render sytles. Work can be done using real world measurements or at any scale, or measurement units.

Using Cycles is possible to create photorealistic representations of the interaction between different materials and lighting conditions. The lights and materials properties are based on materials and lights from the real world.

To create more abstracted, or line only or sketch like rendering you can use Freestyle.

The software is designed to accommodate a wide variety of artists that use it for different purposes, like film/video animation, illustration, along with game creation or 3d printing, so very specialized tools or workflows might be a bit cumbersome or mind-bending for those coming from technical applications. The modeling tools sometimes use other logic than that of CAD packages but are still quite sophisticated. Some tools will have different names but at the end they do the same thing.

Like all other software it has its strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

I think @atomicbezierslinger might be correct, but I think Blender can be great for architectural renderings, but not necessarily designing. There are plugins that add Architectural Desktop-like features, but Blender is more like Maya than AutoCAD.

Two good resources to see what's capable in architectural rendering in Blender are: [Blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/) and [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/index.php) (for example: [this recent rendering posted by the artist](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?395947))